# Return value of object coming as undefined from method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, javascript-objects

I have following code

```
getBetIdDetails = () => {
  const data = {
    accountName: localStorage.getItem("custId"), //"bz_uetest1", //
    betId: this.props.BetSlipDataObj.selectedBetId,
    agentName: "",
  };

  let url = `/rest/jarvis/reports/v1/getBetSlipDetail`;
  var _this = this;

  post(url, data)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data && response.data.betSlipDetails) {
        //some assignment statements
        this.updateReducer({
          ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
        });
      } else {
        //some assignment statements
        this.updateReducer({
          ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
        });
      }
    })
    .then(() =>
      this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betDetails.data.forEach(function (
        value,
        index,
        theArray
      ) {
        _this.getBetDetailsByEvent(value)
          ? (theArray[index]["eventDetails"] = _this.getBetDetailsByEvent(
              value
            )) //"hello world";
          : "";
      })
    );
  console.log(this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betDetails.data);
};
```

Here is the code for `getBetDetailsByEvent`. In `getBetDetailsByEvent` I am returning the object based on condition. Just before return, `console.log` is printing correct values inside the object.

```
getBetDetailsByEvent = (value, clickSendDetails) => {
  this.props.BetSlipDataObj.eventDetailsLoaded = false;
  this.updateReducer({
    ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
  });
  let list = {};
  list = value;
  const data = {
    //setting data
  };

  if (data.eventId == null) return;
  let url = `/rest/jarvis/reports/v1/getBetEventData`;

  post(url, data).then((response) => {
    if (response.data) {
      this.props.BetSlipDataObj.isLoaded = true;
      if (response.data.sportingBetsGameDetail != null) {
        //some assignment statements
        this.updateReducer({
          ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
        });
        console.log(this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betEventResponse);
        return this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betEventResponse;
        if (clickSendDetails == true)
          this.clickSendDetailsToTraders("sportingBetsGameDetail");
      } else if (response.data && response.data.sportingBetsOptionBetDetail) {
        //some assignment statements
        this.updateReducer({
          ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
        });
        console.log(this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betEventSBOptionalResponse);
        return this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betEventSBOptionalResponse;
        if (clickSendDetails == true)
          this.clickSendDetailsToTraders("sportingBetsOptionBetDetail");
      } else {
        this.updateReducer({
          ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
        });
        return "";
      }
      //this.props.BetSlipDataObj.eventTileData = response.data;
    } else {
      this.updateReducer({
        ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
      });
    }
    if (this.eventMap.size == this.props.BetSlipDataObj.sportsbookBetsLenght) {
      this.props.BetSlipDataObj.eventDetailsLoaded = true;
      this.updateReducer({
        ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
      });
      return "";
    }
  });
};
```

Just before the return statement, I am printing the object and it is having a value, but from the place where the method is called, it's giving undefined.

Can someone please let me know where I am making mistake?

Comment: Your `getBetDetailsByEvent` function is a void return, so it ***is*** returning `undefined`. You can return `post` Promise. I would answer but it isn't clear what you are trying to do with a return value.

Comment: In `foreach` loop  `getBetDetailsByEvent` will be called based on number of rows. I want to save every retrun value in `["eventDetails"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the value right after you call a promise. A promise is asynchronous, this is the reason we use callbacks (`.then()` for example), so that we know when the value is available. Right after the `post()` call, the props are not yet updated.

I simplified your example:

```
post(url, data)
    .then((response) => {
      this.updateReducer({
        ...this.props.BetSlipDataObj,
      }); // set the props, called 2nd
    })
  });
  console.log(this.props.BetSlipDataObj.betDetails.data); // undefined, this is called 1st
};
```

See live example on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-kalam-1vlp3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: So what can be solution here ? How can I get the data ?

Comment: You're already getting the data in `.then((response) => { /* use response.data here */ })`. This function will get called when the data is received.

Comment: You can read more about Promises at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and more examples of `.then()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)